# bootstrap 4 @media max-width

Tags: bootstrap

Для мобильников с разрешением 720px заданные стили отображаются произвольно, в мобильном браузере google chrome заданные стили никак не хотят применяться, а в браузере Яндекс работают отлично, что не так?

Код такой используется

```
@media (max-width: 720px) {

  header .col-sm-3 {
      background-color: blueviolet;
     } 

}
```

Answer (score 4):

проверьте наличие тега

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Свойство width определяет размер окна просмотра. Он может быть установлен на определенное количество пикселей, скажем,width=600 или на специальное значение device-width, которое означает ширину экрана в пикселях CSS в масштабе 100%. (Есть также соответствующие значения height и device-height, которые могут быть полезны для страниц с элементами, которые изменяют размер или положение на основе высоты окна просмотра).

Свойство initial-scale контролирует уровень масштабирования при первой загрузке страницы. Свойства maximum-scale, minimum-scale и user-scalable определяют, как пользователям разрешено увеличивать или уменьшать страницу.